# Meaning of "What's shaking?"

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, idioms

I can guess it probably means "what's happening", or "what's up". Am I right? I am curious where this phrase comes from and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_shaking) says:

> Interjection
>
> what's shaking
>
> 1. (*slang*) what is happening?

---

The phrase is Afro-American in origin, from the 1950s. From 1970's [*Black Slang: a Dictionary of Afro-American talk* By Clarence Major](http://books.google.com/books?id=p2o9AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA102&dq=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&f=false):

> **Shaking:** (1950's) same as *Happening*; *example,* "What's shaking?"

---

Here's some published uses from the 1950s.

From [*Reports of cases determined in the courts of appeal of the state of California*](http://books.google.com/books?id=DYY7AAAAIAAJ&q=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&dq=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&hl=en&ei=Dr0VTtSTEYms8gOIl4Qc&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwADiYAg), 1957:

[image: Reports of cases determined in the courts of appeal of the state of California]

From [*Sig Byrd's Houston* by Sigman Byrd](http://books.google.com/books?id=SDNBAAAAIAAJ&q=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&dq=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&hl=en&ei=Dr0VTtSTEYms8gOIl4Qc&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAziYAg), 1955:

[image: Sig Byrd's Houston]

---

There's also this from [1931](http://books.google.com/books?id=liJEAAAAYAAJ&q=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&dq=%22what%27s%20shaking%22&hl=en&ei=Dr0VTtSTEYms8gOIl4Qc&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBjiYAg), it could be related but it's probably not:

> "They've found you on the beach,
>   that's what you hear, what's shaking
>   your shoulder. Your heart's still
>   beating. You've got time to go back,
>   to live, to find someone else than
>   Sue. Sue's meeting John on Thursday.
>   Go back to the beach.

---

Anyway, as to how to use *What's shaking?*, the excellently titled *[Flappers 2 Rappers: American Youth Slang](http://books.google.com/books?ei=8b4VTsHwHY_G-Qbz2fkf&ct=result&sqi=2&id=LR15Tui8qYgC&dq=%22what%27s%20shaking%22%20dictionary&q=%22what%27s%20shaking%22#search_anchor)* (1996) gives some variations:

[image: Flappers 2 Rappers: American Youth Slang]

Comment: my gf asked me that when I took off my underwear.

Comment: Is it ok to say in the same sense "what shook?

Answer (score -1):

Shaking or swinging is indeed what certain parts of the adult body can do. As a native speaker and city dweller, I can say that by intonation, that reference is the etymology.  Similar to "How's your sorry ass been?" of "How's it hangin'?"

Do not use the expression with your grandparents, but only with peers.